# jquery lowest nested selector

Tags: jquery, nested, selector

I would like to slideUp all children of ".sub-menu" selectors for the following code:

```
<div ID="browse_container">
    <div class="sub-menu">Root
        <div class="sub-menu">▷ English</div>
        <div class="sub-menu">▷ Maths
            <div class="sub-menu">Year 1</div>
            <div class="sub-menu">Year 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-menu">▷ Science</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').live('click', function(){
        $(this).children().slideUp()
    })
});
```

But this slides up "Root", as the sub items of, e.g., "english" are all children of "Root". Can I tell jquery to select the lowers nested "sub-item"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sub-menu').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children().slideUp();
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/omapil/2)

You can stop the event from "bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event."

Now when you click on `Maths`, only the children slide up.

Comment: in newer versions `live` is deprecated, see http://api.jquery.com/live/ , you should use `on` instead.

Comment: @ant I had just added to OP's code but you're right. Updated it to use `on`